# Flow from HBase/Hive/Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hbase, hdfs, apache-phoenix

I am creating a presentation on the flow of data with HDFS, Hive/HBase/Phoenix/Spark. Can anyone tell me if the visual below portrays the correct "sequence" so to speak of data flow. since everything runs mostly on top of HDFS I designed it so it would look like it would be on top of HDFS.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is one way to show the "flow". A better way would be to send arrows from Hive to spark as well since you have that option.